# Custom RPSystemBroadcastPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, replaykit

I'm launching system broadcasting picker used for screen recording on iPhone with `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` button and it works properly. However it seems that there is no way to customize the look of this `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` button. `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` always shows a black dot with a black circle around it and it seems that even the color of this icon cannot be changed. I was also trying to show that system picker popup view (with "Start Broadcast" button which is showed after clicking on `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView`) with `RPBroadcastActivityViewController.load` method however it seems that with this method it is not possible to launch the same system popup picker view which is presented when using `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` button.

Therefore my question is: is there any way to customize the look of this `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` button or just launch the same system broadcasting popup picker view which is launched by `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` with a normal UIButton?

Answer (score 1):

so unfortunately there's no way to change look of this button. However there's a trick which you can use to show broadcast picker with regular UIButton. Just have system picker button added somewhere in the view hierarchy and use this code:

```
self.picker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView()
// ...
for view in self.picker.subviews {
    if let button = view as? UIButton {
        button.sendActions(for: .allEvents)
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure it would go against apple's UX recommendations, so use wisely and at your own risk.